# Is there an upper bound on a prime between $2n$ and $3n$?

Tags: prime-numbers

It is known that there exists a prime $p$ between $2n$ and $3n$. I'd like to know whether there is an upper bound on $p$ or whether there is an upper bound on a prime between $2n$ and $kn$, where $k$ is an odd integer.

Comment: $3n-1{}{}{}{}$?

Answer (score 3):

Your question makes no sense. However...the next prime after some prime $p$ is, on average, approximately $p + \log p.$ Some well known conjectures on large prime gaps, sort of mushed together, suggest that the next prime after $p$ is no larger than $$ p + 3 \; \log^2 p.$$ There is not the slightest hope of proving this, but it holds as far as has been computed, plus it is also true for small primes such as $2.$ See  [GAPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Conjectures_about_gaps_between_primes)

Here are some [TABLES](http://users.cybercity.dk/~dsl522332/math/primegaps/gaps20.htm#top20merit)  about large prime gaps. Given that they do not necessarily print out the prime $p$ just before the gap, we can infer, with gap $g,$ that
$$  \frac{g}{\log^2 p} = \frac{\mbox{merit}^2}{g},     $$
because
$$ \mbox{merit} = \frac{g}{\log p}  $$

See, especially, [CRAMER_GRANVILLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_conjecture#Cram.C3.A9r-Granville_conjecture)

Comment: There are a few things that have been proved. E.g., it's known there's a prime between $n$ and $(1.2)n$ for $n$ exceeding some known $n_0$; also, there's a known $c$, $.5\lt c\lt1$, such that there's a prime between $n$ and $n+n^c$ for $n$ sufficiently large.